# Sum ratios of previous rows values over current row value in a different column by groups in R data.table/frame

Tags: r, data.table

My problem is hopefully easy to understand but nontrivial to put into coding terminology. I will adjust the title for more accurate/general terminology once we figure out what others would look for.
I want to calculate a HHI (Herfindahl index) *on a per day basis*, that is, take the sum of the squared shares of every `industry` by country. `Value_country` is the number of `id`s by country in the previous year and `value_country_industry` is the number of `id`s per country and industry in the previous year.

Calculation example: The HHI on `2017/01/03` calculates as `(3/5)^2 (industry A) + (1/5)^2 (industry B) + (1/5)^2 (industry C) = 0.44` where, the *denominator* equals `value_country` at the respective date and the *numerator* is the most recent `value_country_industry` for every industry (i.e. the share, but at the *current* date. This implies that I cannot just work with the `share` column.)

A solution scaling to larger data (and potentially working with `NA`s) would be ideal (hence, the `data.table` tag).

---

**Example Data**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
ID    <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6")
Date <- c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03","2017-01-02")
Industry <- c("A","A","B","C","A","A")
Country <- c("UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","US")
Value_country<- c(1,4,4,4,5,1)
Value_country_industry<- c(1,2,1,1,3,1)
Share <- c(1,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.6,1)
Desired <- c(1,0.375,0.375,0.375,0.44,1)

dt <- data.frame(id=ID, date=Date, industry=Industry, country=Country, value_country=Value_country, value_country_industry=Value_country_industry, desired_output=Desired)
setDT(dt)[, date := as.Date(date)]
```

Comment: Curious if you could define "larger data" more specifically here, for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: ~2mn rows and 100 columns, ca. 1.2 GB measured with `object.size`

Comment: It's not very common for summing of ratios to be appropriate unless the ratios are just proportions.  It is often more appropriate to average log ratios then anti-log, i.e., use geometric means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to cast the data wider in order to more easily account for the "most recent" value_country_industry" rule.
Then fill down and replace any NA's with 0's.
HHI can then be calculated accross the columns, being sure that it will work regardless of how many industries there are.

```
library(magrittr)
dt_wide <- dt[, -c('desired_output')] %>% 
  setnames(c('value_country', 'value_country_industry'), c('vc', 'vci')) %>% 
  dcast(country + date ~ industry, fun.aggregate = last, fill = NA, 
        value.var = c('vc', 'vci'))
vci_cols <- names(dt_wide) %>% .[grepl('vci', .)]
dt_wide[, (vci_cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type = 'locf'), by = 'country', 
        .SDcols = vci_cols] %>% 
  setnafill(fill = 0L, cols = 3:length(.))
dt_wide[, num := Reduce('+', .SD ^ 2), .SDcols = patterns('vci_')]
dt_wide[, den := Reduce('pmax', .SD ^ 2), .SDcols = patterns('vc_')]
dt_wide[, hhi := num / den]
dt_wide[, c('num', 'den') := NULL]
dt[dt_wide, hhi := hhi, on = c('country', 'date')]
dt
   id       date industry country value_country value_country_industry desired_output   hhi
1:  1 2017-01-01        A      UK             1                      1          1.000 1.000
2:  2 2017-01-02        A      UK             4                      2          0.375 0.375
3:  3 2017-01-02        B      UK             4                      1          0.375 0.375
4:  4 2017-01-02        C      UK             4                      1          0.375 0.375
5:  5 2017-01-03        A      UK             5                      3          0.440 0.440
6:  6 2017-01-02        A      US             1                      1          1.000 1.000
```

Comment: Smart solution that works well on the sample data. Unfortunately, I am getting an error that I have not seen before on the real data:  `Error in CJ(1:334081, 1:7332) : 
  Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 2449481892 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647`.

Comment: I didn't see how big the data was before I posted.  For sure you could separate the value_country calcs from the value_country_industry ones.  But you may still have problems.  Next maybe loop through by country.

Comment: I meant `dcast(country + date ~ industry, fun.aggregate = last, fill = NA, value.var = 'vc')`

Comment: I see where you said you have 100 cols, but only 5 need be involved in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238940/discussion-between-brian-montgomery-and-magasinus).